# How to style border as a forward slashes

Tags: css

I would like to create a border in Css with new a style such as "forward slashes" with a specific height and specific width.
Can anyone help Please
 I tried something like this

```
border: dotted blue;
transform: skew(45deg);
```

but if I change the geight, It will be hollow.
I want a border like this:
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
with less space between slashes.

Comment: You want dotted border? Or solid border will work?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  --border-width: 8px;
  --stripe-distance: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
  right: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
  top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
  bottom: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, black, transparent 1px, transparent var(--stripe-distance), black calc(var(--stripe-distance) + 1px));
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: that you can also simplify like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vo7uj2af/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Using a gradient as the border image, this is just an idea there's room for improvement.

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 110deg, black 0px 1px,  transparent 1.5px 8px, black 8.5px) 10  stretch ;
}
```